# Flip Card Button Not Working

Tags: css, html

I have implemented a flip card. It has a button. Everything works fine but not the button. If I removed the css out of the entire thing, the button works but obviously I lose the effects and flip. I even tried putting a link on the entire image, still the link doesn't work. It looks like something is preventing link in this entire thing. What am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/c5ob0b5n/)

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .flip-card {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
          perspective: 1000;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner,
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card,
.flip-card-inner-front,
.flip-card-inner-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-inner-front,
.flip-card-inner-back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.flip-card-inner-front {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 2;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.flip-card-inner-front span {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.8);
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flip-card-inner-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  background: #cacaca;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flip-card-inner-back-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flip-card-inner-back-text {
  line-height: 1.3;
}
    </style>
```

html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm">  
    <div class="flip-card card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-inner-front" style="background-image: url('images/logobgs/merc200.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="flip-card-inner-back" style="background-image: url('images/logobgs/logobg.jpg')"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/logos/merc.png" width="70" height="70"><br><button class="bg-warning"><small>View Mercedes Cars</small></button></div>
      </div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Can you make a working jsfiddle please?

Comment: I have updated with a fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/c5ob0b5n/
Also if it helps here's the live version = https://www.lucidpolygon.com/db/luxury/

Comment: Do u need `View Mercedes Cars` button to flip on hover ?

Comment: nope. What happens is on desktop it flips on hover. On mobile it flips on touch. The button simply redirects to another page. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You are not using any Bootstrap in your Fiddle. So, why is this question tagged with Bootstrap to begin with?

Comment: Your button works fine. I placed an alert in the onclick event and it fired when clicked. Just don't have any code attached to the button to do anything...

Comment: Yep, seems like JavaScript part is missing :o